# Rcpp Unexpected NaN results

Tags: r, rcpp

I have a complicated equation with lots of pow's and was getting a NaN result. So I broke it into pieces, called temp1 to temp4. `temp4` which is `pow(temp3, 0.25)` is where I get a nan which then results in a NaN being returned.

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
#include <cmath>

using namespace Rcpp;

const double kVal = 273.15;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
 double thermalRadiance(double tas, double wind, double Tg) {
  double temp1 = pow(Tg + kVal, 4.0);
  double temp2 = pow(wind, 0.6) * (Tg - tas);
  double temp3 = (temp1 + 2.5e+8 * temp2);
  double temp4 = pow(temp3, 0.25);
  double tr =  temp4 - kVal;
  Rcpp::Rcout << "tas " << tas <<  " wind " << wind <<  " Tg " << Tg <<  " temp1 " << temp1 <<  " temp2 " << temp2 <<  " temp3 " << temp3 <<  " temp4 " << temp4 <<  " tr " << tr  << std::endl;
  return  tr;
}

/*** R
thermalRadiance(29., 4.5, 17.4)
# test of temp4 in R
-2.37018e+07^.25
*/

tas 29 wind 4.5 Tg 17.4 temp1 7.12662e+09 temp2 -28.6013 temp3 -2.37018e+07 temp4 nan tr nan
[1] NaN

> # test of temp4 in R
> -2.37018e+07^.25
[1] -69.77427
```

Seems really straightforward until I get to the temp4 value. Any assistance greatly appreciated!

Comment: Your test is incorrect.  You should test `(-2.37018e+07)^.25`, because `^` has higher precedence than `-`.  If you do, you'll get NaN in R as well, because negative real numbers can't be taken to fractional powers.

Comment: You are trying to take the 4th root of a negative number. `temp3` is -2.37018e+07.

Comment: One of those Duh moments followed by a head slap. My excuse is ancient math skills.

Comment: Please remove the redundant "in simple repex" from the subject line.  Essentially every StackOverflow question (with a code example) could have it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to take the 4th root of a negative number in C++. Perhaps you should replace `pow(temp3, 0.25)` with `-pow(abs(temp3), 0.25)`

```r
#include <Rcpp.h>
#include <cmath>

using namespace Rcpp;

const double kVal = 273.15;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
 double thermalRadiance(double tas, double wind, double Tg) {
  double temp1 = pow(Tg + kVal, 4.0);
  double temp2 = pow(wind, 0.6) * (Tg - tas);
  double temp3 = (temp1 + 2.5e+8 * temp2);
  double temp4 = -pow(abs(temp3), 0.25);
  double tr =  temp4 - kVal;
  Rcpp::Rcout << "tas " << tas <<  " wind " << wind <<  " Tg " << Tg <<  " temp1 " 
              << temp1 <<  " temp2 " << temp2 <<  " temp3 " << temp3 <<  " temp4 " 
              << temp4 <<  " tr " << tr  << std::endl;
  return  tr;
}
```

Which in R gives you:

```r
thermalRadiance(29., 4.5, 17.4)
tas 29 wind 4.5 Tg 17.4 temp1 7.12662e+09 temp2 -28.6013 temp3 -2.37018e+07 temp4 -69.7743 tr -342.924
[1] -342.9243
```